# AudioKit - Routing Multi-Channel Signal Through App (macOS, swift)

Tags: swift, macos, audio, audiokit, swift4.2

I am interested in developing an app using AudioKit that takes the 5.1 input, processes each channel differently, and then outputs it to a different output device.

What I am attempting right now is to simply passthrough a stereo signal from one input device (Soundflower 2ch) and output it to the built in output (on my MBA).

In my code I get a list of available input and output devices and populate two popup menus.  When I make a selection with the popup menu it sets that device as the input or output.

[image]

```
func changeInputDevice() {

    let currentInputName = audioInputMenu.titleOfSelectedItem
    var currentInputID: UInt32 = 0

    if currentInputName == "None" {
        print("No input device selected")
        return
    }

    if let inputs = AudioKit.inputDevices {
        for device in inputs {
            if device.name == currentInputName {
                currentInputID = device.deviceID
                print("Number of channels: \(device.nInputChannels!)")
            }
        }
    }

    do {
        try AudioKit.setInputDevice(AKDevice(name: currentInputName!, deviceID: currentInputID))
        print("Input Device Initiated")
    } catch {
        print("error loading input device")
    }
}
```

My question now is, where do I go from here to route the input audio to the output, and when working with more channels than stereo, how to I determine, which channel can go to which output?

I've tried creating an AKMicrophone() and setting AudioKit.output to that microphone...

```
func startEngine() {

    let format = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: 48000, channels: 2)

    let inputChannels = AKMicrophone(with: format)

    AudioKit.output = inputChannels

    do {
        try AudioKit.start()
    } catch {
        print("error starting AudioKit Engine")
    }

}
```

...but I get this error in the console:

```
2019-04-03 10:54:25.736287-0400 Studio EQ[6895:3586453] [avae] AVAEInternal.h:70:_AVAE_Check: required condition is false: [AVAudioIONodeImpl.mm:911:SetOutputFormat: (format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate)]
```

All input and output devices are set to 48kHz, 24bit on my system since that is what I use for work.  Is there another type of node I should be using?

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: No unfortunately I have not.